Talk.js User messages are appearing on right side instead of left and header is of the 'Other User'
the chat between parent and caregiver
So on the left panel is the 'parent' and the right the 'caregiver', the avatar for the parent is the lady and caregiver is the guy. However the headers have it reversed and the messages are reversed as well, in both instances the person chatting will have their messages in blue and on the right hand side instead of the left.
First time using TalkJS:
Here is the parent messaging:
"use client";

import { useCallback, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import Talk from "talkjs";
import { useParams, useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";
import { Session, Chatbox } from "@talkjs/react";

function ParentMessagePage() {
  const { roomId } = useParams();
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const parentName = searchParams.get("parentName");
  const caregiverName = searchParams.get("caregiverName");
  const sessionRef = useRef();

  // Extract IDs from roomId
  const [parentId, caregiverId] = roomId ? roomId.split("_") : [];

  // Define the primary user (Parent) as session.me
  const syncUser = useCallback(() => {
    const parentUser = new Talk.User({
      id: parentId,
      name: parentName || "Parent",
      email: `${parentId}@example.com`,
      photoUrl: "https://talkjs.com/new-web/avatar-7.jpg",
      role: "parent",
    });
    console.log("Setting session.me as Parent User:", parentUser);
    return parentUser;
  }, [parentId, parentName]);

  const syncConversation = useCallback(
    (session) => {
      // Define caregiver user only within the conversation
      const caregiverUser = new Talk.User({
        id: caregiverId,
        name: caregiverName || "Caregiver",
        email: `${caregiverId}@example.com`,
        photoUrl: "https://talkjs.com/new-web/avatar-8.jpg",
        role: "caregiver",
      });
      console.log("Adding Caregiver User:", caregiverUser);

      // Create or get the conversation and set participants
      const conversation = session.getOrCreateConversation(roomId);
      conversation.setParticipant(session.me); // Parent as `me`
      conversation.setParticipant(caregiverUser); // Caregiver as secondary participant
      console.log("Conversation Participants:", conversation.participants);

      return conversation;
    },
    [roomId, caregiverId, caregiverName]
  );

  // Confirm that the session is initialized correctly
  useEffect(() => {
    if (sessionRef.current) {
      console.log("Session initialized:", sessionRef.current);
      console.log("Session.me should be Parent:", sessionRef.current.me);
    }
  }, [sessionRef]);

  return (
    <Session
      appId={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_TALKJS_APP_ID}
      syncUser={syncUser}
      sessionRef={sessionRef}
    >
      <Chatbox syncConversation={syncConversation} style={{ width: "100%", height: "500px" }} />
    </Session>
  );
}

export default ParentMessagePage;

the careprovider messaging:
"use client";

import Talk from "talkjs";
import { useCallback } from "react";
import { useParams, useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";
import { Session, Chatbox } from "@talkjs/react";

function CaregiverMessagePage() {
  const { roomId } = useParams();
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const parentName = searchParams.get("parentName");
  const caregiverName = searchParams.get("caregiverName");

  // Extract IDs from roomId
  const [parentId, caregiverId] = roomId ? roomId.split("_") : [];
  console.log("Caregiver ID:", caregiverId)
  console.log("CaregiverMessagePage - roomId:", roomId);

  // Define the primary user (Caregiver) as session.me
  const syncUser = useCallback(() => {
    return new Talk.User({
      id: caregiverId,
      name: caregiverName || "Caregiver",
      email: `${caregiverId}@example.com`,
      photoUrl: "https://talkjs.com/new-web/avatar-8.jpg",
      role: "caregiver",
    });
  }, [caregiverId, caregiverName]);

  const syncConversation = useCallback(
    (session) => {
      const parentUser = new Talk.User({
        id: parentId,
        name: parentName || "Parent",
        email: `${parentId}@example.com`,
        photoUrl: "https://talkjs.com/new-web/avatar-7.jpg",
        role: "parent",
      });

      const conversation = session.getOrCreateConversation(roomId);
      conversation.setParticipant(session.me); // Caregiver as `me`
      conversation.setParticipant(parentUser); // Parent as secondary participant

      console.log("CaregiverMessagePage - Conversation ID:", roomId);
      return conversation;
    },
    [roomId, parentId, parentName]
  );

  return (
    <Session appId={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_TALKJS_APP_ID} syncUser={syncUser}>
      <Chatbox
        syncConversation={syncConversation}
        style={{ width: "100%", height: "500px" }}
      />
    </Session>
  );
}

export default CaregiverMessagePage;

I am using NextJS and app router Ive tried flipping the sync user but it doesnt really do anything but reveserse the problem.
I am using NextJS and app router Ive tried flipping the sync user but it doesnt really do anything but reverse the problem.
I have also tried manipulating the css to no effect.
